# ExopPlayer can not play some m3u8 stream but MX Player / VLC can

Tags: android, video, stream, exoplayer, codec

I am using Exoplayer to play some m3u8 files.
But some of the files are getting played and some can not be played.

But the MX Player / VLC player played all the files successfully.

This is how I am playing the stream :-

```
 player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    playerView.setShowNextButton(false);
    playerView.setShowPreviousButton(false);
    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl);
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    player.prepare();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Video Codec Info:-

[image: Video Codec Info]

Comment: Can you use exoplayer `EventLogger` and paste player logs? There could be several root causes for a link not to be played.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the HTTP access in android. Adding the permission to manifest file solved the issue.